# How does one choose a font that can display text in any alphabet in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I need to display some text that is returned from a web service. The text itself is returned in UTF-8. I need to display the text onscreen in a font that is capable of rendering the text (which could be arabic, japanese, french, hindi, whatever).

At run time, how do I determine which font to use ?
 Is there a single font in iOS that can be used for this situation ?

Comment: UTF-8 should have no problem with System Font. However, if you have characters that goes beyond that (UTF-16, UTF-32, etc), you'd better read [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the system font itself can display all those languages. You also can use the `Helvetica Neue`, works perfectly.

I do it too to display arabic, japanese, korean etc.

You can read this [documentation about unicode](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html).

Comment: rather than "basic font", you are probably referring to "System Font".

Comment: Can you explain ? For example, how would I use this with a UILabel ?

Comment: Nothing to explain. You use it as standard `myLabel.text = MyUTF8String;`